# Passing function as parameter on javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently started to learn javascript and saw this code. It was very different than C++ so please tell me what it means.

```js
function getWeather(lat, lng){
 fetch(
  `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
 )
 .then(function(response){
  return response.json();
 })
 .then(function(json){
  const temp = json.main.temp;
  const place = json.name;
  weather.innerText = `${temp} @ ${place}`;
 });
}
```

so basically it gets api and fetch it. After that it continues with **.then(function(response)** 
I have no idea where that **response** come from. I can guess that response part is something returned from fetch function but still I don't understand how that happens.

```js
const parsedToDos = JSON.parse(loadedToDos);
     //for each takes function and execute function on each items.
     parsedToDos.forEach(function(toDo){
      paintToDo(toDo.text);
     });
```

similar to the previous example, it takes **toDo** as parameter and it is not even global or local variable in this code but still used. Can anyone tell me the logic behind this?

Comment: its called a `Promise`. the function being passed is a callback function. its like using function pointers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API - read through the section in the left nav you will get to the bit explaing the response object in the section for fetch usage

Comment: These are both examples of method chaining, where a method takes an output from a previous method (the new param) and then manipulates that output before returning the data, at which point another chained method may pick up the newly returned response and do some manipulation to it. So, `fetch` returns a response containing a JSON body, which is passed to the first `then` where the JSON is extracted from the response object and returned to the second `then`, where the `temp` and `place` are extracted from the JSON and used for the side-effect of changing the `weather` element in the DOM.

Comment: `fetch` returns a Promise, it is a way to deal asynchronous code.

Comment: Does C++ not have function pointers? It's very similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

Which arguments a function receivedsis determined by the **caller** of the function. If you have the following function

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Then "you" can call it as

```
add(1, 3)
```

Sometimes it is not directly "you" who calls the function, but another function. E.g.

```
function add1(a) {
  return add(a, 1);
}
```

here `add` is called by `add1`. `add1` will always pass `1` as second argument.

In addition to that, sometimes functions accept other functions as arguments and call them at some point. Again an example:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    return callback(40, 2);
}
```

Here `doSomething` accepts a function as argument and will always pass `40` and `2` as arguments. If I pass a function that expects to be passed two numbers it will work as expected:

```
// Works
doSomething(function (a, b) { return a + b; });
```

If I don't not, then I get some unexpected behavior or an error:

```
// Error :(
doSomething(function (a, b) { a.foo.bar = b });
```

But if that happens then I haven't read the documentation properly, because functions which accept callbacks usually explain which arguments are passed to the callback. [For example for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (emphasis mine):

> `forEach()` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays, see example below).
>
> **`callback` is invoked with three arguments:**
>
> - the value of the element
> - the index of the element
> - the Array object being traversed

Similar for `.then`.

---

In summary, arguments are provided by the caller. If you pass a callback to a function then that function will most likely be caller and pass arguments. Read the documentation or look at the source code to find out which arguments these are.